# Secondary payment processor as a fallback on declines

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, stripe-payments, credit-card, braintree

When doing credit card processing online you see a number of declines from the issuing bank of the end user credit card. Some of these are legitimate (internet payments blocked, no money on the account), but a number of them are also automatic fraud system erroneously kicking in.

I was toying with the idea of having a secondary payment processor, and, if the credit card is declined on my primary, retry it again with the secondary one.

Does anyone have any experience from this and/or know if it's a bad idea.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want the fraud protection, why not just disable it on your payment processor account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to pay for two separate merchant accounts, of course, and then you'll have additional time with bookkeeping, too, reconciling accounts from both places instead of just one.

Also, in my experience if fraud filters from one processor are kicking in then they likely will on most others as well.

If it's quick and easy for you to implement the solution you've outlined I'd say it wouldn't hurt anything, but if it's going to take you a bunch of time/money getting that integration done I would question whether it's going to be worth it personally.

Answer (score 0):

Find a payment gateway company that handle multiple merchants at the same time.  They can route certain credit cards to certain issuing banks.  Full disclosure; we do have clients that need this option as a gateway: https://tripayments.com